# Getting Times Zone By Given Format

Tags: php, timezone

How can i get the timezone as `(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)` by using php code?
If there is any php code to get the time zone like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like this to achieve your aim:

```
$tz = date_default_timezone_get(); // or your timezone of choice
$dt = new DateTime;
$dtz = new DateTimeZone($tz);
$off = $dtz->getOffset($dt);
$s = $off >= 0;
$h = abs(floor($off / 3600));
$m = abs($off % 3600);

printf("(GMT%s%02d:%02d) %s", $s ? '+' : '-', $h, $m, $tz);
```

I 'm not sure if there is enough built-in information in PHP to get the exact description you are looking for though; if not, you 'll have to manually map built-in timezone names to your own descriptions (Mountain Time etc).

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/HfH5Y)**.